# Why do we define the magnetic field around a conducting rod as concentric instead of radial?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Why is it that we define the magnetic field around a conducting rod as concentric instead of being radially outwards?

Ok, we know from the Lorentz force law, that the magnetic force is the cross product of velocity and magnetic field, but we might as well have defined magnetic force to be the product of velocity and the magnetic field (like the electric force) and then the magnetic field will overlap with electric field.

Is the circularity of the magnetic field due to convention or is there a physical meaning behind it? I know from relativity that the magnetic force arises from length contraction due to the high speed of electrons, but what does this tell us about the magnetic field?

Comment: Force is a vector quantity, while $\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{b}$ is a scalar

Comment: Sorry, I meant the regular product as in $q\mathbf{E}$

Comment: We are not *defining* the field, we are *calculating* it from Maxwell's laws. I don't understand what you want to ask.

Comment: You can measure magnetic field lines using something like a compass; it actually points along the field lines. Also, a "magnetic monopole" would move along that trajectory, just as an electric monopole (test charge) moves along the electric field lines.

Comment: @ACuriousMind He is probably asking whether it is possible to describe the magnetic phenomena with a vector field $\mathbf B$ which points radially outwards from a current source, with some necessary change of the Lorentz $\textbf v \times \textbf B$ force law

Comment: Yes, roughly...